# Capture all stderr data from multiple subprocess Popens piped together

Tags: python, process, subprocess, pipe, popen

I have multiple subprocess `Popen`s piped together in Python 2.7 through their stdin/stdout as follows:

```
p1 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd1), stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
p2 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd2), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
...
pN = Popen(shlex.split(cmdN), stdin=pN-1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = pN.communicate()
```

Everything works very smoothly as expected; however I would like to capture the stderr of **every** different process, while at the moment I can only capture the one of the final process `pN` through `pN.communicate()`. I know that each stderr can be redirected in a different file, but I would like to know if there is any way to capture the stderr of all the processes after and/or before the final communicate within Python?

Calling communicate for different processes always results in a broken pipe.

---

**EDIT-1**

Is calling `communicate` on each process in the same sequence as in the pipe a correct and acceptable solution?

```
p1 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd1), stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
p2 = Popen(shlex.split(cmd2), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
...
pN = Popen(shlex.split(cmdN), stdin=pN-1.stdout, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

stdout1, stderr1 = p1.communicate()
stdout2, stderr2 = p2.communicate()
...
stdoutN, stderrN = pN.communicate()
```

---

**EDIT-2**

The solution proposed in **EDIT 1** is wrong as it produces errors when `communicate` is called on an already ended process.

The only feasible solution at this time seems to redirect stderr of all processed on files and read those after making sure that all processes terminated with:

```
map(lambda p : p.wait(), (p1, p2, ..., pN))
```

Comment: Hint: https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/selectors.html